# how to set resource route using controller case by ID and on the controller get the id

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-routing, url-parameters

without resource, I can use like this is work:

```
use App/Http/Controller/Aaa/XxxController as AaaXxxController;
use App/Http/Controller/Bbb/XxxController as BbbXxxController;
Route::get( "/aaa", [ AaaXxxController::class, "index" ] )
    ->defaults( "xxxID", "aaa" );
Route::get( "/bbb", [ BbbXxxController::class, "index" ] )
    ->defaults( "xxxID", "aaa" );
```

but when I using on resource method like this:

```
use App/Http/Controller/Aaa/XxxController as AaaXxxController;
use App/Http/Controller/Bbb/XxxController as BbbXxxController;
Route::resource( "/aaa", AaaXxxController::class)
    ->defaults( "xxxID", "aaa" );
Route::resource( "/bbb", BbbXxxController::class)
    ->defaults( "xxxID", "bbb" );
```

I get the error message:
Method Illuminate\Routing\PendingResourceRegistration::defaults does not exist.

the App/Http/Controller/Aaa/XxxController and App/Http/Controller/Aaa/XxxController is extends App/Http/Controller/XxxController

App/Http/Controller/XxxController like this:

```
public function index( $xxxID ) {
    //...
}
......
public function update( Request $request, $xxxID, $id ) {
    //...
}
......
```

Comment: why not directly add the value in `$xxxId` ? like `public function update($xxxID = "value") {}`

Comment: because AaaController and BbbController extends to share controller than the $xxxId is control nav detail of view open or not

Comment: actually, I have aaa folder and bbb folder, than I have a many controller on aaa folder and bbb folder, I don't want to add the value on each folder, it is so stupid, I have no idea how I can do. If have no other method, I just can set protected parameter on each controller but it is so stupid.